# Reinstall zlib on centos

Tags: python, zlib, centos5

I faced "segmentation fault error" with "yum". Then I realised that there's a problem with zlib, but I messed it when trying to fix it. Now I need to reinstall zlib. since "yum" is no longer working I need to reinstall zlib through rpm or  wget or some other way.
could any one tell me the step by step procedure of reinstalling zlib?

Answer (score 0):

I thought guys in here are much more active.
anyway it ended up that I contacted my server company and they checked the hard disk and said that there is physical fault with the hard disk. I backed up my data on another server. they changed the hard disks and installed a fresh OS.
now every thing's fine